# How can I analyse (frequency) audio played by iTunes or any other player on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I need to analyse the live frequency playing by audioPlayer of the iPhone.

For example if  iTunes is playing a song, I want to analyse the song that is playing while I am in my app, get frequency info of the song that is playing.

Can someone share any code of how you do that?

I understood that there is a way of analysing the audio played to the speakers also.

Comment: Read about audio routing http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/12/ios-7s-new-inter-app-audio-introduces-universal-audio-routing-between-apps/ . To analyze the frequencies, you can use FFT.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial at Apple for AurioTouch, although that code is fairly fugly.

This might help:

http://prog.roaringshark.com/?p=5